# Calculating daily average using hourly data in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, average

I want to get daily data such as net radiation, sensible heat flux and latent heat flux. NOAA NWS National Centers for Environmental Prediction (NCEP)[ee.ImageCollection("NOAA/CFSV2/FOR6H")] has 6 hours averaged data. I'm trying to get daily average using 6 hourly data in above source.

Could you share the code to calculate daily data from hourly data?

Answer (score 6):

You should try to provide some code in your questions. Even if you only manage to create an image collection and display a single image on the map.

To get daily means, you can do like this:

```
var startDate = ee.Date('2020-01-01')
var endDate = ee.Date('2020-01-05')

var collection = ee.ImageCollection("NOAA/CFSV2/FOR6H")

var numberOfDays = endDate.difference(startDate, 'days')
var daily = ee.ImageCollection(
  ee.List.sequence(0, numberOfDays.subtract(1))
    .map(function (dayOffset) {
      var start = startDate.advance(dayOffset, 'days')
      var end = start.advance(1, 'days')
      return collection
        .filterDate(start, end)
        .mean()
    })
)
Map.addLayer(daily.first().select(0), {min: 100, max: 450, palette: 'blue,green,yellow,orange,red'})
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/d11f67a6cfcef02992d96c53a7f835ed

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. I want to get a time series of data. Could you please help me to get the time series of daily latent heat flux data                                                
                                                                                                                                
var geometry = ee.Geometry.Point([80.73,8.26]);
var startDate = ee.Date('2017-01-01')
var endDate = ee.Date('2020-01-05')
var collection = ee.ImageCollection("NOAA/CFSV2/FOR6H")
.filterDate(startDate, endDate)
.select('Latent_heat_net_flux_surface_6_Hour_Average');

Comment: https://code.earthengine.google.com/fbe32df03d956bb6c47ccfbb25ad5b3a

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind support.

Comment: https://code.earthengine.google.com/21099fca23b4d4e3d09dd11b05e55ff4                             Here I want to repeat the above process for 15 points. Please help me to simplify the code instead of repeating the same code for 15 times. Thank You.