# Export time series data from 3 bands in single Image Collection based on single coordinate

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have an Image Collection consist of daily `Tmin`, `Tmean` and `Tmax`. I am able to create chart for each Band (with `series` and `doySeriesByYear`) based on single coordinate and make it feature collection so I am able to export it to Goodle Drive.

I also create a chart using all Bands, so I have `Tmin`, `Tmean` and `Tmax` visualised in single chart (see below picture). But I am unable to make it as a feature, so I can't export it to Google Drive.

[image: Chart all Band]

How can I solve the above problem?

Here's my [code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/34419fa5c1a39d982956c236237d4d10)

```js
  //---  Air temperature
var Tair_vis = {
  min: 0,
  max: 40,
  palette: [
    '040274', '040281', '0502a3', '0502b8', '0502ce', '0502e6',
    '0602ff', '235cb1', '307ef3', '269db1', '30c8e2', '32d3ef',
    '3be285', '3ff38f', '86e26f', '3ae237', 'b5e22e', 'd6e21f',
    'fff705', 'ffd611', 'ffb613', 'ff8b13', 'ff6e08', 'ff500d',
    'ff0000', 'de0101', 'c21301', 'a71001', '911003'
  ],
};

  //---  To extract timeseries information by location
var geometry = ee.Geometry.Point([168.3793, -17.6257]); // Efate Island, Vanuatu

var GLDAS = ee.ImageCollection('NASA/GLDAS/V20/NOAH/G025/T3H'); // GLDAS20
// var GLDAS = ee.ImageCollection('NASA/GLDAS/V021/NOAH/G025/T3H'); //GLDAS21

  //---  Function to Celsius
function toCelcius(image){
  var Temp = image.select('Tair_f_inst').subtract(273.15);
  var overwrite = true;
  var result = image.addBands(Temp, ['Tair_f_inst'], overwrite);
  return result; 
}

  //---  GLDAS air temperature in degC
var GLDAS_Tair = GLDAS.select(['Tair_f_inst']).map(toCelcius);

  //---  Start and End date
var startDate = ee.Date('1948-01-01'); 
var endDate = ee.Date('1950-01-01'); 

  //---  Generate NumberOfDays
var numberOfDays = endDate.difference(startDate, 'days');
print(numberOfDays);

  //---  Adapted from Daniel Wiell's answer at https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/358532
  //---  on how to calculate daily averages from hourly data

  //---  Summarize 3-hour temperature data to daily min, mean and max
  //---  MINIMUM
var Tair_min = ee.ImageCollection(
  ee.List.sequence(0, numberOfDays.subtract(1))
    .map(function (dayOffset) {
      var start = startDate.advance(dayOffset, 'days');
      var end = start.advance(1, 'days');
      return GLDAS_Tair
        .filterDate(start, end)
        .min()
        .rename('Tmin')
        .set('system:index', start.format('YYYY-MM-dd'))
        .set('date', start.format('YYYY-MM-dd'))
        .set('system:time_start', start.millis())
        .set('system:time_end', start.millis());
    })
);

  //---  MEAN
var Tair_mean = ee.ImageCollection(
  ee.List.sequence(0, numberOfDays.subtract(1))
    .map(function (dayOffset) {
      var start = startDate.advance(dayOffset, 'days');
      var end = start.advance(1, 'days');
      return GLDAS_Tair
        .filterDate(start, end)
        .mean()
        .rename('Tmean')
        .set('system:index', start.format('YYYY-MM-dd'))
        .set('date', start.format('YYYY-MM-dd'))
        .set('system:time_start', start.millis())
        .set('system:time_end', start.millis());
    })
);

  //---  MAXIMUM
var Tair_max = ee.ImageCollection(
  ee.List.sequence(0, numberOfDays.subtract(1))
    .map(function (dayOffset) {
      var start = startDate.advance(dayOffset, 'days');
      var end = start.advance(1, 'days');
      return GLDAS_Tair
        .filterDate(start, end)
        .max()
        .rename('Tmax')
        .set('system:index', start.format('YYYY-MM-dd'))
        .set('date', start.format('YYYY-MM-dd'))
        .set('system:time_start', start.millis())
        .set('system:time_end', start.millis());
    })
);

  //---  Sorted time
var Tair_min_sorted = Tair_min.sort("system:time_start");
// print(Tair_min_sorted);
var Tair_mean_sorted = Tair_mean.sort("system:time_start");
// print(Tair_mean_sorted);
var Tair_max_sorted = Tair_max.sort("system:time_start");
// print(Tair_max_sorted);

  //---  Combine min - max - mean into single image collection
var Tair_temp = Tair_min.combine(Tair_mean).combine(Tair_max);  
var Tair = Tair_temp.sort("system:time_start");
print(Tair);

  //---  Map vis
  //---  To check example of the daily aggregate result, add the first image to map 
Map.addLayer(Tair.select('Tmin').first(), Tair_vis, 'Daily Tmin');
Map.addLayer(Tair.select('Tmean').first(), Tair_vis, 'Daily Tmean');
Map.addLayer(Tair.select('Tmax').first(), Tair_vis, 'Daily Tmax');

  //---  Chart setting
var titleTmin = {title: 'Daily Min Temperature',hAxis: {title: 'Time'},vAxis: {title: 'degC'}};
var titleTmean = {title: 'Daily Mean Temperature',hAxis: {title: 'Time'},vAxis: {title: 'degC'}};
var titleTmax = {title: 'Daily Max Temperature',hAxis: {title: 'Time'},vAxis: {title: 'degC'}};

  //---  Define the chart and print it to the console.

  //---  Chart1 - Mean Temperature
var chartTmean1 = ui.Chart.image.doySeriesByYear({
    imageCollection: Tair,
    bandName:'Tmean', 
    region: geometry, 
    regionReducer: ee.Reducer.mean(), 
    scale: 27830,
    sameDayReducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    startDay: 1,
    endDay: 366
  });
chartTmean1 = chartTmean1.setOptions(titleTmean);
print(chartTmean1);

  //---  Chart2 - Mean Temperature
var chartTmean2 = ui.Chart.image.series({
  imageCollection: Tair.select('Tmean'), 
  region: geometry, 
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(), 
  scale: 27830
});
chartTmean2 = chartTmean2.setOptions(titleTmean);
print(chartTmean2);

  //---  Feature collection
var timeSeriesTmean = Tair.map(function (image) {
  var value = image.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    geometry: geometry,
    scale: image.projection().nominalScale()
  }).get('Tmean');
  return ee.Feature(null, {
    'value': value,
    'date': image.date().format('yyyy-MM-dd'),
    'system:time_start': image.date().millis()
  });
});
print(timeSeriesTmean);

Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: timeSeriesTmean, 
  description: 'portvila_tmean',
  folder: 'GLDAS_csv',
  selectors: ['date', 'value']
});


  //---  All temperature
var chartTair = 
    ui.Chart.image
      .series({
        imageCollection: Tair, 
        region: geometry, 
        reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(), 
        scale: 27830
      })
      .setSeriesNames(['Tmax', 'Tmean', 'Tmin'])
      .setOptions({
          title: 'Daily Air Temperature',
          hAxis: {title: 'Date', titleTextStyle: {italic: false, bold: true}},
          vAxis: {
            title: 'degC',
            titleTextStyle: {italic: false, bold: true}
          },
          lineWidth: 1,
          colors: ['cf513e', '1d6b99', '76b349'],
          curveType: 'function'
        });
print(chartTair);

var timeSeriesTair = Tair.map(function (image) {
  var value = image.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    geometry: geometry,
    scale: image.projection().nominalScale()
  }).get('Tmin', 'Tmean', 'Tmax');
  return ee.Feature(null, {
    'value': value,
    'date': image.date().format('yyyy-MM-dd'),
    'system:time_start': image.date().millis()
  });
});
print(timeSeriesTair);


Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: timeSeriesTair, 
  description: 'portvila_tair',
  folder: 'GLDAS_csv',
  selectors: ['date', 'Tmin', 'Tmean', 'Tmax']
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is `get('Tmin', 'Tmean', 'Tmax')`. According to the `ee.Dictionary.get()` docs:

> **get(key, defaultValue)**
>
> Extracts a named value from a dictionary. If the dictionary does not
> contain the given key, then defaultValue is returned, unless it is
> null.

You could perhaps put `Tmin`, `tMean`, and `Tmax` in separate columns.

```
var timeSeriesTair = Tair.map(function (image) {
  var mean = image.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    geometry: geometry,
    scale: image.projection().nominalScale()
  })
  return ee.Feature(null, mean)
    .set({
      'date': image.date().format('yyyy-MM-dd'),
      'system:time_start': image.date().millis()
    })
})
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/5506c969f266e198f50588dc5ffb5c85

Comment: Thank you! Works as expected.